# autofilter with “or” condition between 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty sure the only way I can do this is with a helper column but wanted to ask the experts before I threw in the towel.

I have 2 columns that I would like to filter by but need the results to show for both criteria.
So if either column "S" (field #19) or column "CK" (field #89) are equal to "Red" I want to see them.

Anyone know how to solve?

```
Sub Filter_by_Red_CD_LE()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Dim ddate As String
ddate = Month(Date)
Dim r As Range

Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("$a$10:$cp$500")
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$a$10:$cp$500").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="Red"
ActiveSheet.Range("$a$10:$cp$500").AutoFilter Field:=89, Criteria1:="Red"
Range(Cells(r.Rows.Count + 1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Range("$a$10:$cp$500").Sort Key1:=Range("B10"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
    xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 47
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 11
Range("A8").Value = "Current Filter = REd LE/CD"
Worksheets("Pipeline").Shapes("Drop Down 11").ControlFormat.Value = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: I would use AdvancedFilter instead of AutoFilter.

Comment: @NicholasHunter hmmm, don’t know how to do that, can you help me with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes that the first row of your data range contains column headers.

First you need to define the data range and the criteria range.

Then you set up the criteria range with (1) the column headers of the columns you want to apply the selection criteria to, and (2) the selection values.

S='Red' **OR** CK='Red' looks like this.

| CQ | CR |
| --- | --- |
| Col S header | Col CK header |
| Red |  |
|  | Red |

S='Red' **AND** CK='Red' would look like this.

| CQ | CR |
| --- | --- |
| Col S header | Col CK header |
| Red | Red |

VBA code looks like this.

```
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim criteriaRange As Range

' Replace worksheet name as required
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Define the data range.
    Set dataRange = .Range("A10:CP500")
    
    'Define criteria range
    Set criteriaRange = .Range("CQ10:CR12")
    
    ' Copy column headers
    .Cells(10, "CQ").Value = .Cells(10, "S").Value
    .Cells(10, "CR").Value = .Cells(10, "CK").Value
    
    ' Criteria values
    .Cells(11, "CQ").Value = "Red"
    .Cells(12, "CR").Value = "Red"

End With

' Apply the filter.
dataRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, criteriaRange
```

When you're finished, you can easily clear the criteria range like this.

```
criteriaRange.Clear
```

Advanced filter documentation is here [Range.AdvancedFilter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter) but it's not super helpful. Plenty of other examples if you google Excel VBA Range.AdvancedFilter.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas but I am getting an "Invalid procedure call or argument" error at this part: 
    .Cells("CQ10").Value = .Cells("S10").Value
    .Cells("CR10").Value = .Cells("CK10").Value

Comment: oops. fixed. try it now.

Comment: Wow! this worked great. Sorry to ask for more but how would I incorporate more criteria,  I want to exclude any row that has the string "*Doc*" in column AZ and any row with the string "*Broker*" in column H and any row with the string "*Subord*" in column AZ?

Comment: Never mind Nicholas, I used your code as a guide and after a little trial and error I figured out how to add additional criteria. Thank you very much for your help :-)